# optional var not getting set

Tags: swift, delegates, swift3

```
cell.delegate? = self
```

cell.delegate is still nil.

Comment: I am not sure what you trying to achieve from your code?. I can't see any data array assigned to your collectionView?.What do you thing `cell.delegate? = self` will do if there is nothing to show?. there should be 1000s of similar questions related to your problem in SO.search `how to populate colectionView in Swift`?.

Comment: this means.you found the solution?

Comment: let me see i can fix your problem.where you assigning  data for your collectionView?

Comment: Run the project.let me know collectionView populating your assigned text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell.delegate? = self` should be `cell.delegate = self`